# AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute when querying using join

Tags: join, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'd like to join query with calendarID across the tables to see if given the (user) ID in channel table, is the channelID of calendarID empty? if so, write to it.

Models.py:

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    calendarID = Column(String(100), unique=False, nullable = True)
    Channel = relationship('Channel', backref='owner')
class Channel(db.Model):  
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    calendarID = Column(String(100), unique=False, nullable = True)
    channelID = Column(String(100), unique=False, nullable = True)
    owner_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'))
```

Routes.py:

```
def activateChannel(id):
    """
    reactivates the channel for notification to be received
    """
    import random
    import string
    breakpoint()
    user = db.session.query(User, Channel).filter(User.id==Channel.id).filter(User.calendarID==Channel.calendarID)
    if user.channelID is None:
        user.channelID = ''
    else:
        pass
```

However, I get:

```
*** AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'channelID'
```

Answer (score 0):

The name channelID is defined inside the Channel class.
Where in the "User" class, and hence in the "User" objects, its name is "Channel".
So your code should be ...

```
if user.Channel is None:
        user.Channel = ''
```

Side note: I think unique is False by default, so there's no need to do it explicitly. Also, it's a convention to name attributes with lowercase, "user.channel"

Comment: don't think that helps ` user.Channel
*** AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'Channel' `

Comment: Are you sure your models.py work?
There's a bracket missing at the end of this line:
owner_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id')

Comment: yeah it does and sorry that was just a typo

Comment: One potential reason is that user is a list of users, not just a single user.
Another possibility is your query doesn't return a thing.
Wish this helps

Comment: Oh I think I finally got it. The issue is in backref.
Firstly you need to define __tablename__ = 'user', __tablename__ = 'channel' in each class.
Then change backref value to be 'user'.
You can check the first example here:
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/backref.html

Comment: Thanks for the follow. I started getting `(Pdb) user.id
*** AttributeError: 'result' object has no attribute 'id'
(Pdb) user.channelID
*** AttributeError: 'result' object has no attribute 'channelID'`

Comment: Also, I am interested in accessing the channelID attribute in Channel and not just Channel

Comment: You're getting 'result' object has no attribute 'channelID' because it's like a list of users
Do this 

for u in user:
  u.channelID

Comment: I don't think you can no longer write to that even if results were to come

Answer (score 0):

Get all channels for a given user (by `user_id`) where the `calendarID` is not set:

```
q = session.query(Channel).join(User).filter(User.id == id).filter(Channel.calendarID == None)
```